# Writing and reading string in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to make my app remember my name when i write it and then tell it, but instead of telling my name it tells the name of file where name is stored ("MySharedName").
this is my code :

```
    nameData = getSharedPreferences(namee, 0);
        File l = new File("/data/data/cannon.gaming.appname/shared_prefs/MySharedName.xml");
        if(l.exists()){
        }else{

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = nameData.edit();
            editor.putString("user", String.valueOf(namee));
            editor.commit();
        }

if(String.valueOf(namee).equals("MySharedName"))
                        {
                            home.speak(abc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            home.speak(abcc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(abccc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(abcccc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(name, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            home.speak(hello, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            home.speak(abc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(abcc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(abccc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            home.speak(abcccc, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                        }

    if(String.valueOf(namee).equals("MySharedName"))
                {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = nameData.edit();
                    editor.putString("user", String.valueOf(matches));
                    editor.commit();
                    home.speak(meet, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    home.speak(now, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
```

Comment: Can I see more code?

Answer (score 0):

To write A Preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putString ("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve a preference

```
String value = prefs.getString ("key", "defaultValue");
```